# For which values of $m$ I get this for any $x$?

Tags: functions, inequality

For which values of $m$ I get this for any $x$?

$$ (2m-4)x^2 + (m+1)x -1 > 3x - 2 $$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on how you might tackle this. Two possible strategies came to my mind, plus some simple observations. So I would suggest you think a bit about possible approaches and let us know what you have tried.

Comment: As a hint, you want a quadratic function to never cross the $x$-axis, and also have it always positive. When does a function have no real roots? (From there, either the whole graph lies above or below the $x$-axis. What factor determines which of these is the case?)

Comment: I don't have any idea how to solve it..

Comment: @KM101, your hint is false. And confused. My hint: put all terms to the left side. What have you learned about sign of a quadratic function ?

Comment: @ama How exactly is my hint false?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

It is equivalent to 
$$ (2m-4)x^2+(m-2)x+1 > 0\quad\text{for all }x, $$
so it means this is a quadratic polynomial with no real root, and with a positive leading coefficient.

Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

We see that $m=2$ is valid.

For $m\neq2$ we obtain the following system:
$$2m-4>0$$ and $$(m-2)^2-4(2m-4)<0.$$
Can you end it now?